# Concurrent Mirroring, Log Shipping and Replication of a Database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am currently mirroring and log shipping a production database.  I use log shipping (every 10 minutes in order to be able restore back to a point time and i mirror to ensure I have a realtime copy of the database.   These solutions are great for DR but I can't query off of the Mirror or the Logship database in there restoring states.  Right now I am restoring a copy backup of the database to a "reporting" server on a daily basis but I need to be able to query near real time data (and don't want to use the OLTP DB).   I am considering enabling replication of this database for reporting purposes.

Does any one know of or have any experience in concurrently Mirroring, Log Shipping and Replicating a Database in SQL Server 2005?  What pitfalls, performance issues or other gotchas will I run into?

PS. I am limited to SQL 2005.

Many thanks

S PAcheco

Answer (score 1):

When you setup log shipping you have the option to specify the restore mode of the database. If you specify 'STANDBY' the database is put into a read only state which you can query. If you look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188916%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and search for restore_mode you will see the option. I believe you can set this through the GUI as well.